# "System.SObjectException: Contact.AccountId does not belong to SObject type Contact" error often in Summer '16

Tags: apex, sobject, summer-16, sobjectfield, dynamic-apex

We are seeing a test failure in a couple of our Continuous Integration builds (that deploy the same code) with the error:

> System.SObjectException: Contact.AccountId does not belong to SObject
>   type Contact

The error is occurring in the `put` in this code (where the `SObjectField` array is hard coded and so has been successfully compiled):

```
public static SObject copyFieldsToNewSob(SObject sob, SObjectField[] fields) {
    SObject result = sob.getSObjectType().newSObject();
    for (SObjectField f : fields) {
        if (!String.valueOf(f).equalsIgnoreCase('Id')) {
            result.put(f, sob.get(f));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

One org fails all the time and the other 2 out of 3 times.

I'll raise a case, but before I do is anyone else seeing this or knows if it will be fixed soon?

Comment: I feel sorry for the sob that has to deal with that! Ah unfortunate abbreviations. Not as bad as std I suppose.

Comment: @Keith if you skip the 'AccountId' field, does put work for the other fields? Is the Account a Person Account? There is a blurb in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm) "Field tokens aren't available for person accounts. If you access Schema.Account.fieldname, you'll get an exception error. Instead, specify the field name as a string."

Comment: @ArpiJakab Thanks for that comment; not sure its the cause here but good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing from this:

```
result.put(f, sob.get(f));
```

to this:

```
result.put(String.valueOf(f), sob.get(f));
```

works around the problem..

Comment: I suppose that's a fairly obvious workaround. Did you ever find a Known Issue or open a case?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I left it to my colleague who couldn't create a simple test case that failed so in the end we gave up pursuing the case. There is probably a bug in there somewhere...